# MySQL said: Documentation #2054 - The server requested authentication method unknown to the client

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

There are similar question in the thread but here I am obliged to mention this issue because being a newbie learner I couldn't figure out and resolve this problem. Sorry for my long English, I hope you care to help me.

By the way, I have the XAMPP Control Panel installed on my windows already and I had worked on to create few databases in the localhost/phpmyadmin (browser). Today, I had downloaded and installed MySQL-installer-community from this [Link](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=479862). I followed all the procedures to install it and configured it correctly.(The default port number was 33060 and I don't change that while installing the MySQL Installer).

But later by some reason I had to approach to my previous XAMPP Control Panel and tried to start APACHE and MySQL. APACHE was started but MySQL cannot be started and got terminated automatically. Later I found that MySQL in XAMPP Panel is running on same ports as I had not changed the port number while configuring the MySQL installer. So, I changed the default MySQL port number i.e. 3306 on XAMPP Control Panel to 3307 by making the changes in my.ini file as shown in the embedded image: 
[Changes on my.ini file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7VKH.png)

Later, while I restart the XAMPP Control Panel, MySQL starts without delivering any errors [SEE HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hygVc.png) but still the Access is denied on the browser. For image, see this: 
[Access denied in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKYD3.png)

However, through shell alongside, I can fetch the databases even though the access is denied in browser.
[Accessing Database via Shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4G1u.png)

Thus, I am seeking for the help on why can't I access the databases via localhost/phpmyadmin on the browser? Please guide me thoroughly!!

Comment: Check my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/58615936/6312647. It is for ubuntu, but I think it could help you in windows too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution on my own:
For this we have to go to the drive where the XAMPP is installed (for me it's C:\xampp). Then, we have to look for the folder *phpmyadmin* and click on that. 
Inside the *phpmyadmin*, we have to look for the file *config.inc* and open with notepad or any other text editor. Look for the line $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1:3306'; and change it to $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1:3307';

This works for me.